# Chromium new version update on DotNewBrowser

Tags: version, upgrade, dotnetbrowser

we have some performance issues on chromium 69 version and it seems fixed on latest chromium version. Do you have any plan to upgrade DotNetBrowser version to latest one?

Comment: Chromium update is one of our priority tasks at the moment. Unfortunately, there is no exact ETA for now. You can follow our releases or contact us to get status updates.

Comment: as the chromium version is only 69 i think its just stopped working with sites. one example is https://dashboard.stripe.com/login can't get it working on any computer or using your sample apps